# maintain user login status in express.js

Tags: node.js, session, authentication, express

I am using passport to login my users. When a user logs into my app, the username will be displayed in the header.

This is my `header.jade`:

```
div#header_content
input(type='text',name='search',id='globle_search')
span#user_status
    if(req.isAuthenticated())
        a(class='user_menu_btn',href='home', target='_blank' )  req.user.username
        a(class='user_menu_btn',href='logout') Logout
    else
        a(id='login_btn',href='login',class='user_status_btn') login
```

If I run the app, I get an error that says:

```
 ReferenceError: F:\shopping\views\includes\header.jade:4
 req is not defined
```

This is my index route:

```
app.get('/',index.index);

exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

How do I maintain the login status in the header?

Comment: check these two examples https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/auth https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/jade

Comment: its not what am looking for.i know how to log user in but how to display the login status in the header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access `req` within the view, it has to be member of the `locals` object passed to the view engine -- which it won't be by default.

```
// before: app.use(app.router);
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.req = req;
    next();
});
```

Though, since `user` and `isAuthenticated` are the what you need from `req`, you can just attach them directly:

```
// before: app.use(app.router);
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals({
        get user() { // as a getter to delay retrieval until `res.render()`
            return req.user;
        },

        isAuthenticated: function () {
            return req.user != null;
        }
    })

    next();
});
```

```
if isAuthenticated()
    // ...
    a(...) #{user.username}
else
    // ...
```

See [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals) and [`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

middleware:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if ( req.session.user ) {
      req.session.logged_in = true;
    }
    res.locals.sess = req.session;
    next();
});
```

route:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

view:

```
if(sess.logged_in)
    a(class='user_menu_btn',href='home', target='_blank' )  sess.user.username
    a(class='user_menu_btn',href='logout') Logout
else
```